# Expected value of $(e^X-1)^\alpha$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, special-functions

I'm stuck with an integral since a while:
$$
\int_0^\infty (e^x-1)^\alpha e^{ -\frac{1}{2}  (\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} dx\\
\alpha\in [0,1]
$$

$\sim$expected value of $(e^X-1)^\alpha$ where X follows a normal distribution $\mu \, \sigma$

I've managed to find an approximation (via a approximation of $(e^x-1)^\alpha\sim x^\alpha+\frac{\alpha}{2}x^{\alpha+1}+...$) and it's sufficient for my need but I feel like the exact solution exists. I've learned a lot of new techniques when trying to compute this integral :)

I'm looking for a closed formula made up of combination/composition of (most probably) special functions.

Do you have some tips?

maybe starting with

$$
\int_0^\infty (e^x-1)^\alpha e^{ -x^2} dx\\
$$

is a good start point but I'm not more successful.

Any idea?

Thanks!